# Toyata Avalon non-VVT-i / VVt-i swap

Tags: toyota, avalon

I have a Toyota Avalon (2002 Australian build) with a non-VVt-i 1MZ-FE engine (same as used globally). If an engine swap becomes necessary would it be feasible to install a VVT-i version of the same engine and use my existing valve train, or even just lock the valve timing mechanism?

The reason I ask is that the non-VVT-i engines are becoming quite hard to locate locally and the computers for the VVT-i engines cost nearly as much as the engine itself - if you can even get hold of one. YMMV, depending on where you are.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can find a non VVTi 1MZ from a camry or from an engine importer?  I would check with the dealer to see if the bottom end is compatible with your heads and electronics.

Another alternative would be to swap an entire VVTi 1MZ - longblock + ecu + sensors + wiring harness.  I don't think it would be neccessarily a whole lot more work, and you get yourself a nice little upgrade in the process.